# Check if a form field is not empty

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to check if an input field is not empty. If not empty, process the form. The field is ID of ninja_forms_field_66. The problem is that when I enter "0" in this field, it thinks the field is empty and it won't pass validation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#ninja_forms_field_50').click(function() { 
        var ninja_forms_field_46=$( "#ninja_forms_field_46" ).val();
        if( (ninja_forms_field_46 !='' && ninja_forms_field_301 !='' && ninja_forms_field_66 !='undefined' && ninja_forms_field_71 !='' && ninja_forms_field_75 !='' && ninja_forms_field_304 !='' && ninja_forms_field_64 !='' && ninja_forms_field_63 !='' && ninja_forms_field_95.checked) || (document.getElementById("47_checklist").checked == true) )    

        {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#rLo') });  
        }
    }); 
});
```

edit: I have tried it like  ninja_forms_field_66 !=''  and   ninja_forms_field_66 !='undefined'

Comment: Incidentally, you have not defined a `ninja_forms_field_66 ` variable. You have only defined #46.

Comment: Are you parsing the value of the field to an `Integer`?

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the field: `ninja_forms_field_46.length > 0`

You should also trim the value:

```
 var ninja_forms_field_46= $.trim($("#ninja_forms_field_46" ).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(ninja_forms_field_66) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the string length function and check if it is bigger than 0 - str.length > 0.
[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)